# Calling VBScript method from Javascript is not working in IE11 windows 10

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, vbscript

If i try to call VB Script method from JavaScript its saying method undfined error.

Here is the code, this code works fine in IE 11 of windows 7, however the same code does not work in Windows 10.

in Windows 11, we get the popup on click of a button, if we select the date we are getting **"getFormattedDate method undefined error".** In IE i debugged the breakpoint hits fine, i can view the selected date in watch but its breaking in Javascript and control is not going to VBScript function.

```
<script language="javaScript">

    function getSelectedDate(e)
    {

     getFormattedDate("<%=request("format")%>", e.name);        

    }
</script>

<script language="VBScript">


    function getFormattedDate(strFormat, strDate)

        select case lcase(strFormat)

        end select

        window.opener.document.forms("<%=request("form")%>").item("<%=request("element")%>").value = str        
        window.self.close
    end function
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what this question has to do with VB.NET.

Comment: VBScript only runs on intranets.